# Azure server names vs Azure database names

Tags: sql-server, azure

Let's say I have one Azure subscription and 2 Azure instances:  Dev-instance.database.windows.net for developer testing, and Prod-instance.windows.net for production work.  I want to create a new database named 'Employee'on both instances.  Can I name the database the same on both instances, or do the database names have to be unique since I only have one subscription?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database name can be same on both instances with in the same subscription. See the picture below. I have same database in 2 different server but in the same subscription.

[image]